# How does the styleSheet property in Internet Explorer work?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have already found the solution to the problem that I was having. But I don't quite get why it works.
The following is what happens in IE5 - IE10 (the styleSheet property is replaced by sheet in IE11).

```
var foo = document.createElement("style");
foo.type = "text/css";
console.log(foo.styleSheet);
```

The above code will log a styleSheet Object.

```
var bar = document.createElement("link");
bar.rel = "stylesheet";
bar.type = "text/css";
bar.href = "styles.css";
console.log(bar.styleSheet);
```

This code logs "null".

So my question is **Why can I access the styleSheet property of a newly created style element but not a newly created link element?**

Some notes and observations:

- When I inspect the **bar** variable in IE developer tools, I can clearly see that **bar.styleSheet** is not actually null. I can see all of the properties of the styleSheet object.
- The *type="text/css"* is actually not required for either element to be considered a style sheet. If you exclude this, you can still see the styleSheet Object for both in the developer tools. If you append the elements to the document, the style rules will be read and applied. The only difference thing is, if you don't set *type="text/css"* for a newly created style element (like **foo**), it's
  styleSheet property will be null.
- If you run a "for in" loop on **bar** and try to access the **bar.styleSheet** property within or after the loop, it is no longer null and has somehow magically turned into a styleSheet object.
- As expected, when you add **bar** to the head of the document, you will be able to access the **bar.styleSheet** property.

That last note also brings up a side question which is **Why are you able to access the styleSheet property of *foo* before inserting the element it into the document?** I ask this because according to this documentation from Microsoft on the [styleSheet object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> A styleSheet object is available for a style sheet only if it is "included in a document" with a style or link element...

I did not append foo to the document in my code, so why can I access its styleSheet object?

I am not looking for a "solution" but an explanation of why the newly created elements behave this way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is a fiddle, both returns undefined http://jsfiddle.net/Nq7Yk/ on Mac FF. In my Win 7 Vm, IE 11, both returns undefined as well. Which browser were you using to get the results?

Comment: Its for IE 5 through IE 10.

Comment: well I know for sure console.log() does not work in IE8 so I am not sure how you got it to return null

Comment: Try alerting it. Im using IE 11 and changing the document mode in developer tools.

Comment: It seems that the style tag is already in head and the link tag is not (after inspection with ie developer tool)

Comment: I am not sure why the style tag gets added before any appending, perhaps that's the real question. I can also see the tag in FF but the log does not return anything. So this could be an issue with IE11. The fact that it is not returning anything is the correct behaviour since nothing has been appened

Comment: My guess: For the element `style` it is pretty clear that it’ll contain a stylesheet – whereas `link` could possible be anything else apart from a stylesheet, for example a `prev`/`next` reference, an `icon` or whatever the `rel` attribute allows for. What I’d like to know – does the first one with the `style` element also work if you _don’t_ set `foo.type = "text/css"`? That would IMHO indicate that for a `style` element IE assumes it’ll be a stylesheet no matter what, whereas for a `link` it will only determine that after the linked resource is actually loaded …

Comment: Not showing up on mine. But id that is what is happening that what explain everything

Comment: Yes both work if you  don't include text/css. But you have to append them to the document in order for it to work without it.

Comment: @Huangism that's what I was thinking. according to documentation, the foo way shouldn't be working at all since it hasn't been appended to the document.

Comment: @CBroe That makes sense. But I'm still wondering why I am able to access the styleSheet property in bar in a "for in" loop before I insert it in the document

Comment: Well maybe I was wrong here, and it does not depend on `style` being specific in its use for stylesheets whereas `link` is not. Maybe IE starts to load the external resource assigned via `href` as soon as it is set (would make sense, same happens with `Image` objects after all once their `src` is set) – and this whole thing is just a _timing_ issue? Maybe your for-in-loop takes “long enough” for the resource to have finished loading and parsing in the meantime, so there _is_ a “stylesheet” to access then …

Comment: … whereas with the `style` element it is there _immediately_, because that does not reference an _external_ resource …? Maybe try to verify that, by calling your `console.log(bar.styleSheet)` with a little delay using `setTimeout(function(){console.log(bar.styleSheet)}, 100)` – does this log something else than `null` then …?

Comment: @CBroe. I tried that. No luck.